Why does the LCM of first $k$ natural numbers appear here in this way?
Let $A(b, n)$ be the number of integer tuples $(x_1, \dots, x_{m+1})$
such that $0 \le x_i \le b-1$ and $|x_i - x_{i+1}| = d_i$ for all $i$, where $(d_1, \dots, d_m)$ is the base-$b$ expansion of the non-negative integer $n$, for $ b \geq 1$.
Let $S_k(b) = \sum_{i=0}^{b-1} A(b, \underbrace{i i i \cdots i_b}_{k \text{ digits}}).$
Here are some interesting sums:
$$ 
S_1(b) = b^2
$$
$$ 
S_2(b) = \left\lceil \frac{b(3b-2)}{2} \right\rceil
$$
What's more interesting is that for a given $k$ the sequence we get by finding the second difference of $S_k(b)$ is periodic, and the length of the period seems to be equal to LCM of first $k$ natural numbers (I have verified it upto $k=10$). Can it proved/disproved that the period length is equal to the LCM of first $k$ natural numbers?
If it's true, I am unable to see any reason why the LCM appears in this particular situation, and i want to know why this happens , what's the connection.

If your notation $(i,i,\dots k;times)$ is meant to denote the number $n = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} i b^j$, there's no need to mention base-$b$ expansion of a number $n$, since you are only interested in this very particular form of $n$. You may as well say: Let $A(b, k,i)$ be the number of integer tuples $(x_1, \dots, x_{k+1})$ such that $0 \le x_j \le b-1$ and $|x_j - x_{j+1}| = i$ for all $j$.

@JairTaylor you are right, but i am studying $A(b,n)$ that's why i think i wrote it this way.

Verifying that a sequence matches another sequence with only seven data points is not too convincing - can you get more data?

@JairTaylor i am currently verifying for higher k, i know it isn't much but i get the feeling it is correct, just verified for $k=8$ it holds up for now.

I was able to verify this for some small values of $k$. +1 for a very nice problem.

If a sequence $S$ can be expressed as a term-wise function of simpler sequences, and each of the simpler sequences is periodic, then $S$ is also periodic, and its period divides the LCM of the periods of the simpler sequences. Possibly that's what's happening here: your $S_k$ picks up some behavior from each natural number up to $k$.

If your main concern is the second difference of $S_k$, then you should formulate and phrase your question in terms of that. Besides, what exactly is second difference ? Are you referring to something like $S_{k+2} - 2S_{k+1} + S_k$ ??

Well, I can prove that LCM is divisible by the period, is this good enough for you?

Rephrasing the problem
To simplify notation, we will fix $k$ and omit it as a variable.
Let $W(b)$ be the set of all $k$ step walks on the integers in $[0,b]$ with constant step size. When we refer to a walk, we will implicitly assume it to be an element of $W(b)$.
Then $W(b)-W(b-1)$ is the set of walks that hit $b$. By symmetry, this has the same number of elements as the set $U(b)$ of walks that hit $0$. Then $V(b)=U(b)-U(b-1)$ consists of all walks that both hit $0$ and $b$.
Since $|W(b)|=S_{k}(b+1)$, we want to show that $|V(b)|$ has period $L=\text{lcm}(1,\ldots,k)$. We can show this as follows.
Counting $|V(b)|$
Every walk in $V(b)$ must have a step size $d$ that divides $b$ (otherwise they wouldn't be able to hit both $0$ and $b$). Dividing by $d$, we see that a walk of step size $d$ is in $V(b)$ iff the corresponding step size $1$ walk is in $V(b/d)$. Letting $f(b)$ be the number of $\pm 1$ walks in $V(b)$, we have $$|V(b)|=\sum_{d\mid b}f(b/d)=\sum_{d\mid b}f(d)$$
Since $f(b)=0$ for $b>k$, $$|V(b)|=\sum_{d\mid b,\ d\leq k}f(d)$$ This makes the periodicity apparent. This expression clearly has period $L$, and since $f(d)>0$ for $1\leq d \leq k$, $L$ must be the minimal period: if $|V(b)|$ has minimal period $P$, then $P\mid L$, and $$\sum_{d\mid P,\ d\leq k}f(d)=\sum_{d\mid L,\ d\leq k}f(d)$$ which can only be true if $d\mid P$ for each $1\leq d\leq k$, i.e. $P=L$. $\square$

Such a simple and intuitive solution, just amazing.

I just read this and I have some ideas about why this pattern holds. I'll treat $k$ as a fixed variable and omit it from the definition of $A$.
First of all, as Jair Taylor mentions, we can consider
$$\sum_{ i =0}^{b-1}A(b, i)$$
where $A(b,i)$ is the number of integer tuples $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{k+1})$ so that $0\leq x_j\leq b-1$ for all $j$ and consecutive terms in the tuple differ by exactly $i$. When $i=0$ we just have $A(b, i) = b$, which vanishes when taking the second-order difference, so I'll delete this index from consideration and in the definition of $S$.
Lets define $A_{s}(b,i)$ as the number of tuples counted in $A(b, i)$ with $x_1 = s$.
A key observation of $A_{s}(b,i)$ is that with $x_1= s$ fixed, all other numbers in the tuple are $x_1\pmod{i}$. In particular, choosing $(s, x_2, \ldots, x_{k+1})$ to be in the range $[0, b-1]$ and consecutively differ by $i$ is equivalent to choosing $(\lfloor \frac{s}{i} \rfloor, \lfloor \frac{x_2}{i} \rfloor, \ldots, \lfloor \frac{x_{k+1}}{i} \rfloor)$ which consecutively differ by $1$. As for the range these numbers can be in, denote $R_i(n)$ as the remainder when $n$ is divided by $i$. There are $\left\lfloor \frac{b-1}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b-1)\geq R_i(s)]$ numbers from $0$ to $b-1$ that are $s \pmod{i}$; the bracketed expression is $1$ if the statement is true and $0$ if false. Therefore
$$A_s(b, i) = A_{\lfloor \frac{s}{i}\rfloor}\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b-1}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b-1)\geq R_i(s)],  1\right).$$
We now have
$$S(b) = \sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}A(b, i) = \sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}\sum_{s = 0}^{b-1}A_s(b, i) =  \sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}\sum_{s = 0}^{b-1}A_{\lfloor \frac{s}{i}\rfloor}\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b-1}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b-1)\geq R_i(s)],  1\right)$$
First, parameterize $s$ by $s = qi+r$ which is the quotient and remainder decomposition when dividing $s$ by $i$. Then over all $q,r$ that give rise to $s$ in $[0, b-1]$ we get
$$S(b) = \sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}\sum_{s = 0}^{b-1}A_{\lfloor \frac{s}{i}\rfloor}\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b-1}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b-1)\geq R_i(s)],  1\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}\sum_{q, r}A_{q}\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b-1}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b-1)\geq r],  1\right)$$
However, for fixed $r$, $q$ ranges from $0$ to $\left\lfloor \frac{b-1}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b-1)\geq r]-1$. Therefore, if we define $C(\ell)$ as the number of tuples $(x_1, \ldots, x_{k+1})$ with elements in the range $[0, \ell-1]$ and consecutive differences of $1$ then
$$S(b) = \sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}\sum_{q, r}A_{q}\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b-1}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b-1)\geq r],  1\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}\sum_{r=0}^{i-1}C\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b-1}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b-1)\geq r]\right)$$
Let's take a look at this summation and see what happens if $b$ goes up by $1$, i.e the first-order difference of $S(b)$. First, we get an additional $i=b$ index, which increases the double-sum by $2$ as
$\sum_{r=0}^{b}C\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{b}\right\rfloor +[R_b(b)\geq r]\right) = C(2)+bC(1) = 2$. By the way, this constant increase will be deleted once we consider the second-order difference of $S(b)$. Anyhow, we also have an increase of
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}\sum_{r=0}^{i-1}\left[C\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b)\geq r]\right)-C\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b-1}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b-1)\geq r]\right)\right]$$
This might seem quite complicated, but for fixed $i$ all but one $r$-value will have an inner-bracket evaluation of $0$! Recall that $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(n)\geq r]$ counts the number of numbers in the range $[0, n]$ with remainder $r$ mod $i$ (we previously did this with $n=b-1$). The only way this count changes from $n=b-1$ to $n=b$ is if $b$ is one more number that is $r$ mod $i$, in which case the count changes from $\frac{b-r}{i} = \lfloor \frac{b}{i} \rfloor$ to $\frac{b-r}{i}+1 = \lfloor \frac{b}{i} \rfloor+1$. Therefore
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}\sum_{r=0}^{i-1}\left[C\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b)\geq r]\right)-C\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b-1}{i}\right\rfloor +[R_i(b-1)\geq r]\right)\right] = \sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}\left[C\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{i} \right\rfloor+1\right)-C\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{i} \right\rfloor\right)\right]$$
and
$$S(b+1)-S(b) = 2+\sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}\left[C\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{i} \right\rfloor+1\right)-C\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{i} \right\rfloor\right)\right].$$
This motivates us to define $T(z) = C(z+1)-C(z)$, i.e $T$ is the first-order difference of $C$ so that
$$S(b+1)-S(b) = 2+\sum_{i = 1}^{b-1}T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{i} \right\rfloor\right).$$
Conveniently $T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{b} \right\rfloor\right) = T(1) = C(2)-C(1) = 2$ so
$$S(b+1)-S(b) = \sum_{i = 1}^{b}T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{i} \right\rfloor\right).$$
This is extraordinarily clean! Let's now take the first-order difference of the right-hand side, i.e the second-order difference of $S(b)$. In going from $\sum_{i = 0}^{b}T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{i} \right\rfloor\right)$ to $\sum_{i = 0}^{b+1}T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b+1}{i} \right\rfloor\right)$, we first have the addition of index $i=b+1$ giving an increase of
$T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b+1}{b+1} \right\rfloor\right) = T(1) = 2$. We also have the increase of
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{b}\left(T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b+1}{i} \right\rfloor\right)-T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{i} \right\rfloor\right)\right)$$
For fixed $i$, the difference is $0$ unless $b+1$ is a multiple of $i$. Defining $Y(z) = T(z+1)-T(z)$ we have
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{b}\left(T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b+1}{i} \right\rfloor\right)-T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{b}{i} \right\rfloor\right)\right) = \sum_{i | b+1, i\neq b+1}Y\left(\frac{b+1}{i}-1\right)$$
so
$$(S(b+2)-S(b+1))-(S(b+1)-S(b)) = 2+\sum_{i | b+1, i\neq b+1}Y\left(\frac{b+1}{i}-1\right)$$
and with some re-indexing,
$$S(b+2)-2S(b+1)+S(b) = 2+\sum_{i | b+1, i\neq 1}Y\left(i-1\right)$$
$$S(b+2)-2S(b+1)+S(b) = \sum_{i | b+1}Y\left(i-1\right)$$
Going back to our definitions, we see that $Y(\ell)$ is the second-order difference of $C(\ell)$, which counted the number of $(k+1)$-length tuples with consecutive elements differing by $1$ and lying in $[0, \ell-1]$. Let's split paths counted in $C(\ell+1)$ ($\ell\geq k+1$) into groups depending on if they don't use $0$ or if they don't use $\ell$. Note that no path can not not use $0$ or not use $\ell$ (i.e no path uses both $0$ and $\ell$ as $\ell\geq k+1$). Therefore, we can use the principle of inclusion-exclusion to get
$$C(\ell+1) = \{\text{# paths avoiding }0\}+\{\text{# paths avoiding }\ell\}-\{\text{# paths avoiding }0\text{ and }\ell\}$$
However, the first two expressions imply the path is in $[1, \ell]$ or $[0, \ell-1]$, which give $C(\ell)$ possibilities, and the third expression imply the path is in $[1, \ell-1]$, which gives $C(\ell-1)$ possibilities. Therefore
$$C(\ell+1) = 2\cdot C(\ell)-C(\ell-1)$$
so $Y(\ell-1) = 0$ for $\ell\geq k+1$. Therefore
$$S(b+2)-2S(b+1)+S(b) = \sum_{i | b+1, i\leq k}Y\left(i-1\right)$$
and we are now done, since the set of $i\in [1, k]$ dividing $b+1$ indeed has period exactly $\text{lcm}(1, 2,\ldots k)$. Additionally $Y(\ell-1) \neq 0$ for $\ell \leq k$ as for all such $\ell$ there are actually paths going through $0$ and $\ell$, so modifying the inclusion-exclusion we get $C(\ell+1) >  2\cdot C(\ell)-C(\ell-1)$ and $Y(\ell-1)>0$ for all $1\leq \ell\leq k$.

Lovely solution. Small typo: in "However, for fixed $r$, $q\ldots$" you first of all should have $r$ instead of $\mathcal{R}_i(s)$, and also I am pretty sure that you have to subtract one, $q$ is from $0$ to this number minus $1$ (and this is consistent with how you use it, as $C(l)$ is the number of ways with numbers from $0$ to $l-1$).

Also you perhaps should say that "some re-indexing" is not as trivial, as you replace $\frac{b+1}{i}$ with $i$, which is a, admittedly well-known, trick, and also at the end say that the period can't be smaller than $lcm (1, 2, \ldots , k)$ since on this period it is maximized exactly at the numbers congruent to $-1$ modulo this $lcm$ (this is the trick I myself didn't get, that $Y(l-1) > 0$ for $l\le k$, I only showed that $Y(l-1) = 0$ for $l > k$).

Thanks for letting me know the typos. I'll leave your comment as explanations of the indexing and periodicity, although for the latter note that we don't even need Y(l-1)>0, just that Y(l-1) isn't 0. Thus I feel that the maximum argument you're using, while valid, is restrictive.

I convinced myself that $Y(l-1)\neq 0$ is enough, although it requires some words, unlike with $Y(l-1) > 0$. Nice answer anyways.
